# how can i set my custom layout to DraggableGridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am using `DraggableGridView` to add my custom layout which will have one image view. But childs are not drawing if we add an image view to relative layout which is being added to `DraggableGridView` object, but if we add an image view directly to `DraggableGridView` object then it's drawing. Can you please help me?

Here is the code:

```
gridView = (DraggableGridView)findViewById(R.id.manageGridView);

RelativeLayout gridRow   = new RelativeLayout(ManageClustersActivity.this);
gridRow.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(192,192));


ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(images[i]));
iv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(192,192));


gridRow.addView(iv);

gridView.addView(gridRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more luck with this Fork: https://github.com/lkorth/DraggableGridView

Was looking for the same: only thing i am missing is the onItemClick event: this is not working as far as I could see.

UPDATE: On the Dev branch this seems fixed.
https://github.com/lkorth/DraggableGridView/commit/805bd50f4383cc2c2cbbf231c4a414a5afa60a0f

Adding these lines to the onTouch method (in production, seemed to work as well)

Answer (score 0):

You should add to DraggableGridView.java that

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}
```